# boost locale format percentage

Tags: c++, boost, localization, formatting, locale

I have a problem with boost::locale::format outputting as a percentage.
According to the documentation (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/locale/doc/html/localized_text_formatting.html):

> **Numbers and number manipulators**
>
> Here are the manipulators for number formatting:
>
> ```
> as::number -- format number according to local specifications, it takes into account 
> as::percent -- format number as "percent" format. For example:
>
>         cout << as::percent << 0.25 <<endl;
>
> Would create an output that may look like this:
>
>     25%
> ```

However, the following outputs "0.25":

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/system/system_error.hpp>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << boost::locale::as::percent << 0.25 <<std::endl;
}
```

I have tried imbuing std::cout with an EN-US locale through *std::locale()* as well as a locale generated by *boost::locale::generator* to no avail.

It seems like I'm missing some obvious problem; could anyone hint at it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost.Locale uses 4 backends (ICU, posix, winapi, std), but only ICU backend has percentage feature, that means the library you're using is not compiled with ICU library.

You can see which feature can be used with which backend in [**Supported Features**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/locale/doc/html/using_localization_backends.html) table.

Comment: Thank you! This is indeed what is causing it; I double checked!

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  boost::locale::generator gen;
  std::locale loc = gen("en_US.UTF-8");
  std::cout.imbue(loc);
  std::cout << boost::locale::as::percent << 0.25 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shenanigans. This outputs 0.25 for me... What is your default locale?

Comment: It could be your system locale setting is corrupt. What does `locale` print?

Comment: Mhhh it's printing English_United States.1252. I should add this is on a Win7 SP1. I tried on two machines. What is your boost version?

Comment: I'm using v1.53. What is `1252` supposed to be? It should be `Windows-1252`. If I use `std::locale loc = gen("English_United States.Windows-1252");` it prints `25%`.

Comment: Mhhh... I'm on 1.54. Generating "English_United States.Windows-1252" will still output 0.25 for me with your posted code... I can see though it's setting the percentage facet flag in the class when I step through boost :/ I have not been able to coerce it into printing any percentage sign with any options!

Comment: Please confirm that you're linking against the boost_locale library. It's not header-only! You should get linker errors in that case but you never know with those windows compilers...

Comment: I must be! If I take out "#include <boost/system/system_error.hpp>", libboost_locale-vc100-mt-gd-1_54.lib has unresolved symbols to boost::system::error_category... Which gets me thinking maybe there is something wonky there... Let me check that.

Comment: That sounds like you're linking together apples and oranges. Please check your linker settings and/or versions of libraries and headers.

Comment: Well, I'm not quite sure why the boost system lib isn't pragma'd by boost::locale to be linked. I tried with the dynamic libraries, but percentages still don't get printed. I'll accept your answer though since this is beyond the scope of the question and apparently the issue is not with my usage of boost::locale as initially thought.